# Swapping two files in a directory on bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script that reads two files in a directory, display the content, swap the files and display the contents again.

I researched on how to swap two files and obtained the swap method. However, the method is giving me an error when I run the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
file1="$1"
file2="$2"

function readFile() {
for file in `ls`
do
  cat $file
done

}
function swap()
{
echo "Swapping"
TMP=$(mktemp -d)

 mv "$1" $TMP/tempfile
 mv "$2" "$file1"
 mv $TMP/tempfile "$file2"
 [ -e $TMP/tempfile ] && echo "Error!" || rm -r $TMP
 }
 cd ~
 cd test

 readFile $file1 $file2
 swap $file1 $file2
 readFile $file1 $file2
```

I am getting an error " mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/tmp/tmp.jduY2Yk6xi/tempfile': No such file or directory
" 
How can I achieve the swap? Also, any improvement of the code will be appreciated.

Comment: Moving through a fixed name file in the /tmp/ folder is at risk if another user or window is performing the same operation. Better to move through the current folder anyway, as it is likely on the same device, also use `mktmp` to generate a unique name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question I am not sure this meets all your criteria. But if you just need a content swap of 2 files, you use this very simple script.

It will accept the 2 files you want to swap. Read the contents of each. Save the first file as tmp. Then overwrite file1 with the contents of file2. Then, overwrite file2 with the contents of the tmp file(file1). Lastly it will read the contents again

```
#!/bin/sh
file1="$1"
file2="$2"

cat  $file1 $file2
mv $file1 tmp
mv $file2 $file1
mv tmp $file2
cat  $file1 $file2
```

To run this

```
script.sh file1.txt file2.txt
```

results

```
World 
hello
hello
World
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer actually worked. However, I have been unable to modify the code so that it can take the names of the files in the directory and performing the swapping operation on them. For instance, in my test directory, I have two files, hello.txt and welcome.txt. How can I achieve the swap without literally typing in the names?I must be missing something on how to assign the names as variables.

Comment: if they are constant you can replace the "$1" and "$2" with "/path/to/file" If you are trying to dynamically read them you will have write a loop that searches for them